# Перевод формата PDF в DWG

Tags: pdf, autocad

Необходимо перевести многостраничный файл формата PDF, имеющий встроенные изображения, в формат DWG. 
При этом файл PDF был экпортирован не из Autocad. Если бы это было так, говорят, что проблемы с экспортом бы не было.

Пробовал использовать для этого Adobe Illustrator CS3 - на выходе шрифты получаются белого цвета. При этом страницы файла PDF открываются по отдельности.

Подскажите решение ситуации.

Comment: PDF это сложный объект в основном состоящий из картинок и текста и непонятного другого мусора. DWG это набор примитивов (линий, полигонов), которых, в основном, нету в PDF. Возможно Вас интересует как перевести PDF в картинки в вставить их как растр в чертеж?

Answer (score 1):

По сути пдф это контейнер. Если файл создан с векторными картинками то можно еще импортировать в векторный редактор (CorelDraw), а потом экспорт в AutoCad. Но все ровно на выходе получиться чертеж, где скажем дуга будет нарисована не с помощью 3 точек а намного больше. А если пдф из растворных картинок то все будет намного хуже.

Answer (score -1):

UPD: есть уже куча готовых сервисов, для преобразования напрямую.
Список возможностей для конвертации через доп ПО,либо онлайн:
[ссылка на список](https://www.iskysoft.com/pdf-tips/convert-pdf-to-dwg-autocad-dxf.html)

еще 2 варианта [програмно](http://freesoft.ru/pdf_to_dwg_converter) либо [через сайт](http://cadsofttools.ru/pdf-to-dwg-online/)
*со старыми форматами*: Экспорт в doc формат, сторонними программами и попробовать посмотреть в Word'е как *CAD объект.

Но скорее всего это уже только картинка, и по любому придется обводить или воспользоваться авто обрисовками вида растр2вектор

Comment: Вы правда не видите разницы между DOC и DWG?

Comment: в ворд можно импортировать объекты автокад! Я сталкивался по работе с такими конвертациями. Иногда удавалось вытащить объект. но зачастую это была просто картинка. все зависит от упакощика pdf  а word лиш подскажет !

Comment: уже есть конвертер напрямую, без усложнений [программа](http://freesoft.ru/pdf_to_dwg_converter)  и онлайн  [ссылка](http://cadsofttools.ru/pdf-to-dwg-online/)

Comment: И что? Автору нужно как раз обратное - ему нужен документ Автокада на выходе, а не Ворда.

Comment: переделал в главном ответе.